# MySQL output not formatted when executed through php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get formatted output from mysql as it normally shows when executed from a shell. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4597030/1767412) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4597034/1767412), but it's not working for me.

When I run this in my shell for instance:

```
mysql -e "select language_id, name, image from `language`;" my_database
```

I get the expected output:

```
+-------------+-----------+--------+
| language_id | name      | image  |
+-------------+-----------+--------+
|           1 | English   | gb.png |
|           2 | Français  | fr.png |
+-------------+-----------+--------+
```

But when I do the same thing from the php cli:

```
passthru('mysql -e "select language_id, name, image from `language`;" my_database');
```

It comes out with no formatting:

```
language_id name    image
1   English gb.png
2   Français    fr.png
```

I've tried `passthru`, `system`, `exec`, and `shell_exec` but all return the same unformatted output. **Why is the output different when run from php?**

Comment: Never mind, based on the other answers I see that you're running this from the CLI.

Comment: Do you just need something that will be consistent between CLI and shell execution? Maybe `\G`?

Comment: @user3783243 - thanks, yeah I noticed `\G` behaves the same, which only makes me all the more confused about why the standard output is different.  But I need the standard ascii table, not html

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/35534673/3783243 would work for you? Can't find much documentation on vertical vs. horizontal display processors. The `\G` invokes the vertical so whatever is handling the horizontal must vary

Comment: @user3783243 - maybe?  But it still doesn't answer my question.  I'm trying to understand the mechanics of this more than anything else -whydoes it behave differently to begin with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) on the `mysql` command you can see the lines

```
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
```

which are system calls for checking terminal properties of `stdin` and `stdout` (see [`tty_ioctl(4)`](https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl)).

This means, that `mysql` **is checking whether it outputs to a terminal/tty or into a pipe** and behaving differently depending on that.
Since all the commands PHP offers are based on forking the process and piping the output back into PHP, you won't be able to make `mysql` behave like it was run in a real terminal.

*Note*: You can reproduce this behavior in your shell by calling

```sh
mysql -e "select language_id, name, image from `language`;" my_database | tee
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the command to:

```
passthru('mysql -t -e "select language_id, name, image from `language`;" my_database');
```

The `-t` or `--table` switch forces tabular display of results.

Comment: Yes that works.  Although this explains how to get the desired output, it still doesn't quite explain *why* that flag is needed running from within php but not directly from command line.  I have a feeling there are some default flags set in the shell environment somewhere but would be really helpful if you can pinpoint the exact reason why it's behaving differently.

Comment: Basically, what's happening is mysql detects that its output is not going to stdout -- it's going to php.  When that happens it skips pretty-printing.  ls and other unix command-line utilities commonly do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ mysql -r -u root -e 'select now()'
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2020-03-25 16:44:06 |
+---------------------+
```

`-r` can also be spelled `--raw`.

See also `--batch` and `--silent`.  The whole list:  `man mysql`.

As for the "why"...  PHP->shell->mysql is too contorted.  (Granted, it is quick and dirty, but...)  When using PHP, you should connect to the database and format the output using PHP.

Answer (score -2):

What does it looks formatted is the cli application. Php will fetch raw results from your table. you will have to do the formatting.

One way to do this (if you wanna display it in the browser) is:

```
//assume $row as your fetch result as an array and $results as tour result set

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>language_id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>image</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while ($row = $results->fetch()) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['language_id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['image'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not a web application and I'm not asking how to format the results - I'm asking *why* mysql is not returning the same formatted output from the php cli as it does when I run the command directly in a shell.

Comment: As explained here, you will have to deal with the formatting. Maybe replace some characters or understanding that the character encoding from your viewport can diverge from your CLI application would help you out. Good luck anyways...

Comment: Carlos, did you look at the answers I linked in my question?  This has already been discussed, and again, I'm not asking how to format the output. Please re-read my question.

Comment: Yes. And you got this answered there aswell: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4597190/3435728

Comment: Are you saying that the top, accepted answer is wrong?

Comment: Nope. Just Saying that, maybe, your case could be handled in a different way

Comment: If the accepted answer is correct then why isn't it working for me?  That is the question I'm asking.